# how to retrive data from multipal pojos in hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

hello I have three pojos named like UserTAb, UserData and UserAccess.
I want to retrive all the data from these three pojos using single HQL query.
How can I implement this???

please give full description over this I am new to Hibernate....thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem. I solved it using following way

1. Create a DTO class

   ```
   package com.yourpackage;

   public class UserDTO{

    private UserTAb userTab;

    private UserData userData;

    private UserAccess userAccess;

   // write setter getter here

   public UserDTO(UserTAb userTab,UserData userData,UserAccess userAccess){

     this.userTab=userTab;

     this.userData=userData;

     this.userAccess=userAccess;

    }

   }
   ```
2. Write HQL having proper JOIN. For e.g

   ```
   String hql ="select new com.yourpackage.UserDTO(ut,ud,ua) 
           from UserTab as ut,UserData as ud,UserAccess as ua";
   ```

   UserTab,UserData,UserData is your entity or Domain classes.

   You can refer 
   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html 14.6 section

   Please correct me if I'm wrong